# Let $\mu, \nu$ both have finite second moments and $\nu \in \Pi(\mu, \nu)$. Then the inner product $\langle \cdot, \cdot\rangle$ is $\pi$-integrable

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

In proving [Knott-Smith optimality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4482392/knott-smith-optimality/4482393#4482393), I come across this result. Could you have a check if my attempt is fine, or it contains some logical mistakes?

> **Theorem:** Let $\mu, \nu$ be Borel probability measures on $X:=\mathbb R^d$ such that $\mu, \nu$ both have finite second moments. Let $\pi$ be a Borel probability measure on $X^2$ with marginals $\mu, \nu$. Then the inner product $\langle \cdot, \cdot\rangle$ is $\pi$-integrable.

**My attempt:** Clearly, $\langle \cdot, \cdot\rangle$ is continuous and thus Borel measurable. Because $X^2$ is separable, $\langle \cdot, \cdot\rangle$ [is](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4306079/a-function-f-is-mu-measurable-if-and-only-if-f-is-mathcal-a-measurable) $\pi$-measurable. We have
$$
2\langle x, y\rangle = |x|^2 + |y|^2 - |x-y|^2,
$$
so
$$
\begin{align}
2\int_{X^2} |\langle x, y\rangle| d \pi(x, y) &= \int_{X^2} \big | |x|^2 + |y|^2 - |x-y|^2 \big | d \pi(x, y) \\
& \le \int_{X^2} \big [ |x|^2 + |y|^2 + |x-y|^2 \big ] d \pi(x, y) \\
& \le 3 \int_{X^2} \big [ |x|^2 + |y|^2 \big ] d \pi(x, y) \\
& = 3 \int_{X} |x|^2 d \mu(x) + 2\int_{X} |y|^2 d \nu(y) \\
&< +\infty.
\end{align}
$$

This completes the proof.

Comment: looks legit but let's see (+1)

Comment: Alternatively,  by Cauchy Schwarz inequality and Young's inequality, $$|(x, y)| \leq \|x\|\|y\| \leq \|x\|^2/2 + \|y\|^2/2.$$

Comment: Alternatively,  by Cauchy Schwartz inequality and Young's inequality, $$|(x, y) \leq \|x\|\|y\| \leq \|x\|^2/2 + \|y\|^2/2.$$

Comment: Alternatively,  by Cauchy Schwartz inequality and Young's inequality, $$|(x, y) \leq \|x\|\|y\| \leq \|x\|^2/2 + \|y\|^2/2.$$