# Knott-Smith optimality

Tags: convex-analysis, duality-theorems, optimal-transport

This thread is meant to record a question that I feel interesting during my self-study. I'm very happy to receive your suggestion and comments. See: [SE blog: Answer own Question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) and [MSE meta: Answer own Question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/4680/79762).

---

Let $X,Y$ be topological spaces. Let $\mathcal P(X), \mathcal P(Y)$ be the spaces of all Borel probability measures on $X,Y$ respectively. Let $c: X \times Y \to [0, +\infty]$. Fix $\mu \in \mathcal P(X)$ and $\nu \in \mathcal P(Y)$.

- $\Pi(\mu, \nu)$ is the set of $\pi \in \mathcal P(X \times Y)$ such that for all measurable subsets $A \subset X$ and $B \subset Y$,
  $$
  \pi (A \times Y) = \mu (A) \quad \text{and} \quad \pi (X \times B) = \nu (B).
  $$
- $\Phi_{c}$ is the set of all $(\varphi, \psi) \in L_1 (\mu) \times L_1 (\nu)$ satisfying
  $$
  \varphi(x)+\psi(y) \leq c(x, y)
  $$
  for $\mu$-a.e. $x \in X$ and $\nu$-a.e. $y \in Y$.
- For $\pi \in \mathcal P(X \times Y)$ and $(\varphi, \psi) \in L_1 (\mu) \times L_1 (\nu)$, let
  $$
  \mathbb K (\pi) := \int_{X \times Y} c d \pi \quad \text{and} \quad \mathbb J(\varphi, \psi) := \int_{X} \varphi d \mu+\int_{Y} \psi d \nu .
  $$

> **Theorem:** Let $X = Y = \mathbb R^d$ and assume that $\mu, \nu$ both have finite second moment. Then $\pi$ is a minimizer of $\mathbb K$ over $\Pi(\mu, \nu)$ with cost $c(x,y)  := \frac{1}{2} |x-y|^2$ if and only if there is $\varphi \in L_1 (\mu)$  convex l.s.c. such that $y \in \partial f (x)$ for $\pi$-a.e. $(x, y) \in X \times Y$. Moreover, the pair $(\varphi, \varphi^*)$ is a minimizer of $\mathbb J$ over $\tilde \Phi$ where $\varphi^*$ is the [convex conjugate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4480676/the-map-varphi-e-to-mathbb-r-cup-infty-is-proper-convex-l-s-c-if) and
> $$
> \tilde \Phi := \{(\tilde \varphi, \tilde \psi) \in L_1(\mu) \times L_1 (\nu) \mid \tilde \varphi (x) + \tilde \psi (y) \ge \langle x, y \rangle\}.
> $$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $c_X = c_Y := \frac{1}{2} |\cdot|^2$. We need the following **Lemma**

> [Lemma:](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4449059/a-proof-of-kantorovich-duality) If $X,Y$ are Polish spaces, $c$ l.s.c., then
> $$
> \min_{\pi \in \Pi(\mu, \nu)} \mathbb K (\pi) = \sup _{(\varphi, \psi) \in\Phi_c} \mathbb J (\varphi, \psi) .
> $$
> If, moreover, there are $(c_X, c_Y) \in L_1(\mu) \times \in L_1 (\nu)$ such that $c (x, y) \le c_X(x)+c_Y(y)$ for $\mu$-a.e. $x\in X$ and $\nu$-a.e. $y\in Y$, [then](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4454232/1019043) the maximization
> $$
> \sup_{(\varphi, \psi) \in \Phi_c} J (\varphi, \psi)
> $$
> has a solution of the form $(\psi, \psi^c)$ for some $\psi \in L_1(\mu)$ with $\psi^{cc} = \psi$. Here $\psi^c$ is the $c$-[transform](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4452748/construct-the-c-transform-overline-varphi-overline-psi-of-varphi) of $\psi$.

- $\implies$

Let $\pi^\dagger$ minimize $\mathbb K$ over $\Pi(\mu, \nu)$. By **Lemma**, there is $(\varphi, \varphi^c)$ with $\varphi^{cc} = \varphi$ maximizing $\mathbb J$ over $\Phi_c$. Because $c(x, y) = c_X(x) + c_Y(y) - \langle x, y\rangle$, we have $(\tilde \varphi, \tilde \psi) := (c_X - \varphi, c_Y - \varphi^c)$ minimizes $\mathbb J$ over $\tilde \Phi$. It's can be shown that $\tilde \psi$ is the convex conjugate of $\tilde \varphi$, i.e., $\tilde \psi = \tilde \varphi^*$, and that $\tilde \varphi$ is the convex conjugate of $\tilde \varphi^*$, i.e., $\tilde \varphi = \tilde \varphi^{**}$. By [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4480676/the-map-varphi-e-to-mathbb-r-cup-infty-is-proper-convex-l-s-c-if) result, $\tilde \varphi$ is convex l.s.c. By **Lemma**,
$$
\int_X \tilde \varphi (x) d \mu (x) + \int_Y \tilde \psi (y) d \nu (y)= \int_{X \times Y} \langle x, y\rangle d\pi^\dagger(x, y),
$$
or equivalently
$$
\int_{X \times Y} [\tilde \varphi (x) + \tilde \varphi^* (y) - \langle x, y\rangle] d\pi^\dagger(x, y) = 0.
$$

We have $\tilde \varphi (x) + \tilde \varphi^* (y) - \langle x, y\rangle \ge 0$ for all $(x,y) \in X \times Y$, so $\tilde \varphi (x) + \tilde \varphi^* (y) - \langle x, y\rangle = 0$ for $\pi^\dagger$-a.e. $(x, y) \in X \times Y$. By [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4477468/the-relation-between-convex-conjugate-and-subdifferential) result, $y \in \partial \tilde \varphi (x)$ for $\pi^\dagger$-a.e. $(x, y) \in X \times Y$. It follows from $\tilde \varphi = \tilde \varphi^{**}$ that $\tilde \varphi$ is convex l.s.c.

- $\impliedby$

Let $\pi^\dagger \in \Pi(\mu, \nu)$ and $\tilde \varphi \in L_1 (\mu)$ be such that  $y \in \partial \tilde \varphi (x)$ for $\pi^\dagger$-a.e. $(x, y) \in X \times Y$. Then $\tilde \varphi (x) + \tilde \varphi^* (y) - \langle x, y\rangle = 0$ for $\pi^\dagger$-a.e. $(x, y) \in X \times Y$, so
$$
\int_{X \times Y} [\tilde \varphi (x) + \tilde \varphi^* (y) - \langle x, y\rangle] d\pi^\dagger(x, y) = 0.
$$

By [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4482344/let-mu-nu-both-have-finite-second-moments-and-nu-in-pi-mu-nu-then) result, $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ is $\pi^\dagger$-integrable, so the map $(x, y) \mapsto \tilde \varphi (x) + \tilde \varphi^* (y)$ is also $\pi^\dagger$-integrable. Because $\tilde \varphi$ is $\mu$-integrable, so $\tilde \varphi^* \in L_1 (\nu)$. It follows that
$$
 \int_X\tilde \varphi d \mu + \int_Y \tilde \varphi^* d \nu = \int_{X \times Y}\langle x, y\rangle d\pi^\dagger(x, y).
$$

On the other hand,
$$
 \int_X \varphi' d \mu + \int_Y \psi' d \nu \ge \int_{X \times Y} \langle x, y\rangle d\pi^\dagger(x, y) \quad \forall (\varphi', \psi') \in \tilde \Phi.
$$

It follows that $(\tilde \varphi, \tilde \varphi^*)$ minimizes $\mathbb J$ over $\tilde \Phi$. Because $c(x, y) = c_X(x) + c_Y(y) - \langle x, y\rangle$, we have $(\varphi, \psi) := (c_X - \tilde\varphi, c_Y - \tilde \varphi^*)$ minimizes $\mathbb J$ over $\Phi_c$. This completes the proof.